# missing ; before statement : $(this).closest('tr').find('.tableRow'){\n

Tags: jquery, find, this

```
$('.removeItem').live('click',function(){                                       
                        var postData = {};
                        $(this).closest('tr').find('.tableRow'){
                            var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';
                            postData[keyPrefix + '[index]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_id').text();
                            postData['data['+ index +'][order_id]'] = $('#order_id').text();
                        };
```

I'm not sure if its obvious what i'm trying to do but can anyone spot where i'm going wrong?

EDIT:

Completely my fault, was slightly misleading in my original post, this is my complete code:

```
$('.removeItem').live('click',function(){                                       
                    var postData = {};
                    $(this).closest('tr').find('.tableRow'){
                        var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';
                        postData[keyPrefix + '[index]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_id').text();
                        postData['data['+ index +'][order_id]'] = $('#order_id').text();
                    )};

                $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "deleterow.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: postData,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function()
                        {
                            alert("Item Deleted");
                        }
                    });         
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                calcTotal();
            });
```

Comment: Once you get this far: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.tableRow')` what are you trying to accomplish?  Are you wanting to run the proceeding code block on this wrapped set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the "index" variable, I think that the code should be:

```
$('.removeItem').live('click', function() {
  var postData = {};
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.tableRow').each(function(index) {
    var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';
    postData[keyPrefix + '[index]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.row_id').text();
    postData['data[' + index + '][order_id]'] = $('#order_id').text();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This line here:

```
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.tableRow'){
```

is missing something.  What?  Not clear, but maybe it should be

```
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.tableRow').each(function() {
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  I suspect each() too.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the closing `)` in the `.live` call.

Ignoring the contents of the callback, your code is

```
$('.removeItem').live('click',function(){ ... } ;
                                               ^
```

Notice that you're calling a function with two parameters, but not closing the parentheses.

Comment: sorry have amended my OP, that should make it clearer as to my intentions!

Answer (score 1):

You don't close the "live" function block. you need to add `});` to the end of last line.